# count orders 24hours ago

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order, sales

i want to display at home page how many user have buyed in the last 24hours at our shop

this is my code but the result can never be.

```
$dateToday = date('Y-m-d');
$dateyesterday = date("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime('-24 hours'));
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('product_id');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('gteq' =>$dateyesterday));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('lteq' => $dateToday)); ?>
<?php if ($collection->count() > 0){?>

<div style="float:right; width: 290px; height: 60px; border:#95dc18 dotted; background-color:#3e9de1;">
    <p style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size:10px;">In den letzten 24 Stunden schenkten uns
        <span style=" font-weight:600;"><?php echo $collection->count();?></span>
        Kunden ihr Vertrauen und haben bei uns eingekauft. <br />
        Vielen Herzlichen Dank: <span style=" font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-weight:900;">Frau BlueB</span>
    </p>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

thanks for any help

i found now a solution that works

```
$dateToday = date("Y/m/d");
                    $dateYesterday = date("Y/m/d", strtotime('-24 hours'));


                        $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                            ->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$dateYesterday, 'to'=>$dateToday));
```

a little thing dont work how i want. the script count only the orders from yesterday. but not the orders from today
do anyone hacve a solution for this

Comment: What the error you facing?

Comment: no error but the result is not the result that must be there... e.g. result is 12 but in the last 24hours i have only 2 orders

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$toDate = date('Y-m-d');
$fromDate = date("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime('-24 hours'));     

/* Get the collection */
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate));
    //->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE)); // uncomment this code to get order with status completed
echo count($order);
```

Comment: Is timezone effect on order collection by date like frontend time zone and admin time zone both defferent defferent

Comment: yeah right.. but im the admin and im in the same timezone when i go to frontend. so for me must be the result the same i think

Comment: this code destroys the complete layout and after code nothing to display

Comment: is it displaying any fatal error?

Comment: no error.. page loads till this code and after code only white..

but one question is it possible that this code count how many products sell in the last 24 hours

Comment: No it will count orders only

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and make sure you have order between same date range

```
$dateToday = date('d/m/Y');
$dateyesterday = date("d/m/Y", strtotime('-24 hours'));
$collection= Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$dateyesterday, 'to'=>$dateToday));
```

Comment: i used your code but the result is wrong

i have yesterday 2 orders and after insert your code it shows the result is 12

Comment: Please check now. I have changed date format.Please mark as answer if it's working for you.

Comment: dont work. with your code nothing displayed